# Change Image on Hover in KineticJS

Tags: hover, kineticjs

I'm looking to change an image on hover in KineticJS.  What happens now is that the image just appends to the layer, doesn't actually swap the image.  Without removing the layer, I want to swap the image with another.  Here's my code.

```
       imgObj.onload = function () {
        var image = new Kinetic.Image({
            x: 10,
            y: 10,
            image: imgObj,
            width: 28,
            height: 28,
            id: 'myImage'
        });

        image.on("mouseenter", function (e) {
            document.body.style.cursor = 'pointer';
            imgObj.src = 'myHoverImage.png';
            layer.draw();
        });

        image.on("mouseleave", function () {
            document.body.style.cursor = 'default';
            imgObj.src = 'myImage.png';
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use `.setImage` on the Kinetic.Image to swap to a different image:**

- Preload both images into image objects with `var hoverImage=new Image() ...` and `var blurImage=new Image() ...`.
- Important: Be sure both images have fully loaded using the `.onload` method of the image objects.
- In the event handlers, swap images with `image.setImage(hoverImage)` or `image.setImage(blurImage)`.
- Display the swapped image with `layer.draw()`.

Comment: setImage doesn't appear to do anything for me.  I've tried, but nothing happens.  I've ensured each object is loaded prior as well.